# Unable to perform Response.write

Tags: asp-classic

I have a classic asp page for which I would like to perform the parametrized style asp debugging. The debugging is for finding the SQL used. I am trying to debug in Visual Web developer 2010 but the debug options are grayed out. When I put in `Response.Write` I am getting the asp page as usual. Kindly assist.

The code snippet is below:

```vbs
'//Create Recordset
Set SKUOutput=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
'//Open Recordset

SKUOutput.Open SKUQuery, SKUConnection, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
recordCount=SKUOutput.RecordCount
SKUOutput.Close
Set SKUOutput=Nothing

'//Create Recordset
Set SKUOutput=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

SKUOutput.Open SKUQuery, SKUConnection, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
response.Write SKUQuery
response.End
```

Comment: Error stops the execution flow, so like John answered, you need to put the debug Response.Write before the line that crashing. Another option is to put the code as a remark.

Answer (score 1):

I'd put your response.write statement before skuoutput.open

I think the greyed out options are for .net only - the way to debug classic asp is to run it on your server (or development server) and read the error message in the output.